# Concatenate JSON object using jq

Tags: json, jq

Hi is there a way to add object to json using jq

Main.JSON

```
{
        "person":
        [
            {
            "name": "John",
            "Age": 10
            }
        ]
        "Work":
        [
            {
            "Type":"HR"
            }
        ]
}
```

Sub.JSON

```
{
        "person":
        [
            {
            "name": "smith",
            "Age": 20
            }
        ]
}
```

Using Jq how to add sub person to the main Json so that desired output is

```
{
    "person": [{
            "name": "John",
            "Age": 10
        },
        {
            "name": "smith",
            "Age": 20
        }
    ],
    "Work": [{
        "Type": "HR"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There is a missing comma in Main.json
2. After fixing the problem, the desired result can be obtained by using `+=`, which is analogous to += in other languages, but here uses addition of arrays in the sense of concatenation:

```
 .person += $sub.person
```

Here it is assumed that $sub contains the JSON in Sub.json; assuming your jq supports the --argfile command-line option, this can be accomplished using the following invocation:

```
jq --argfile sub Sub.json '.person += $sub.person' Main.json
```

3.
If your jq does not have the --argfile option, then one possibility would be to use the "slurp" (-s) option as follows:

```
 jq -s '.[1] as $sub | .[0]|.person += $sub.person'  Main.json Sub.json
```

Comment: Thanks For the suggestion currently --argfile is not working with version 1.3. Is there any other option to parse this.